# How do I make a widget float on top of other widgets without affecting the underlying layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to make a widget float on top of another widget without affecting the underlying layout. What I mean by that is, let's see the `TextField` widget with
the decoration's border property set to `OutlinedInputBorder`.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 56,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        labelText: 'Email',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

As you can see, the floating label text is floating on top of the underlying widgets without affecting how the underlying widgets are laid out while the label is sticky to the text field widget. AFAIK, this cannot be accomplished with the `Stack` widget. The same goes for the `IconButton` ripple effect. The ripple effect expands bigger than the actual size of the `IconButton` widget without affecting how the button is laid out in the widget tree. How do make this type of widget structure?

Comment: Do you want to when scrolling your layout, the pinned widget does not affect the other widget?

Comment: @JahidulIslam No, I just want a widget to be on top of other widgets without changing the underlying widget's layout boundary. Consider trying to make the above example with Stack. If you try to put a floating label text and the background text field in Stack then the label wouldn't appear on top of the yellow area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) widget to manipulate the area and bring it back with Stack + Positioned.fill to position the area to bottom layer but keep the layout as the top widget.

Like the example below using `Transform.scale`:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 56,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill( // <- create area same as the "hello" text
          child: Transform.scale( // <- scale 3x the area
            scale: 3,
            child: Container( // <- fill the area with red
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text('hello'),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

And the result:

[image: demo1]

From the example above, the layout still use the "hello" text and the red area expands bigger than the actual size of the "hello" text, just like what you said about IconButton ripple effect.

Another example using `Transform.translate`:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 56,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0, -10),
      child: Text('hello'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

The result is like TextField labelText, same as what you gave the example above.

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this and Do you want like this

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                labelText: 'Email',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 56,
              color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I want. I want to make a widget reusable but this makes the widget tied to other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Overlay widget, it's designed for this purpose